# Why does gensim's simple_preprocess Python tokenizer seem to skip the "i" token?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, gensim

```
list(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess("i you he she I it we you they", deacc=True))
```

gives as result:

```
['you', 'he', 'she', 'it', 'we', 'you', 'they']
```

Is it normal? Are there any words that it skips? Should I use another tokenizer?

BONUS QUESTION:
What does the "deacc=True" paramater mean?

Comment: This is explained in the [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.simple_preprocess), which you should make a habit of reading.

Comment: Thank you, so it was the min_len argument that was set up to 2 by default, nice, thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

As @user2357112-supports-monica mentions in their comment, this is part of the designed behavior of `simple_preprocess()`, per its [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.simple_preprocess), to discard any tokens shorter than `min_len=2` characters.

Your "bonus question" is also answered in that same documentation:

> - **deacc** (bool, optional) – Remove accent marks from tokens using [deaccent()](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.deaccent)?

(The `deaccent()` function is another utility function, documented at the link, which does exactly what the name and documentation suggest: removes accent marks from letters, so that, for example, `'é'` becomes just `'e'`.)